# What are some reasons why parallel code might run slower on a cluster than on a few cores locally?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, plyr, domc

I'm trying to troubleshoot why a process that runs fine serially, and which runs fine in parallel on a local machine (with 3 cores), might slow way down when run on many cores on a cluster.  I can't really make a minimal non-working example, because the code works just fine locally.

I've modified the script to save each worker's output to a file, and I'll aggregate the gobs of files later -- so I don't think that it is communication and aggregation, unless I am missing something.

Here is my output.  I'm showing a wrapper function for a rather complicated process, which I then run once on its own before running it through `plyr`:

```
> analyze_ = function(r){#wrapper function with error handling
+       sti = proc.time()
+       out<-tryCatch(analyze(r)
+               , error=function(e) e, finally=1+1)
+       if(inherits(out, "error")) {
+               out='error!'
+               print(paste("an error happened at",r[1],r[2]))
+       }
+       print(proc.time()-sti
+ }
>
> st = proc.time()
> x = analyze_(xygrid[1,])
[1] "Successfully did -0.25 100.25"
   user  system elapsed
  8.282   0.008   8.286
```

Then I run the code in parallel and everything slows way down:

```
> nodes <- detectCores()
> nodes
[1] 24
> registerDoMC(nodes)
> output<-a_ply(xygrid,1,analyze_, .parallel=T)
[1] "Successfully did 0.25 102.25"
   user  system elapsed
  9.292   0.042 221.954
[1] "Successfully did 0.25 10.25"
   user  system elapsed
  9.298   0.039 221.994
[1] "Successfully did -0.25 102.75"
   user  system elapsed
  9.313   0.054 222.808
[1] "Successfully did -0.25 102.25"
   user  system elapsed
  9.328   0.043 222.832
[1] "Successfully did -0.25 104.25"
   user  system elapsed
  9.250   0.032 223.761
[1] "Successfully did -0.25 103.75"
   user  system elapsed
  9.258   0.038 223.786
```

What are some of the things that might cause this sort of behavior?  As I've said, the function discards the output, maintains benchmark speed when run serially, and works fine on three cores in parallel on my local machine.

Here's a thing:  why is the "elapsed" time almost an exact 24-fold multiple of the "user" time?  (and what is the "user" time anyway?)

**Edit** In response to a question in the comments, here  is a head-to-head comparison of performace in parallel vs in serial.  Parallel is in fact slower.

```
> system.time(analyze_(xygrid[1,]))
   user  system elapsed
  8.223   0.005   8.250
>
> nodes <- detectCores()
> nodes
[1] 24
> registerDoMC(nodes)
>
> system.time(a_ply(xygrid[1:24,],1,analyze_, .parallel=F))
   user  system elapsed
197.666   0.072 197.762
>
> system.time(a_ply(xygrid[1:24,],1,analyze_, .parallel=T))
 system elapsed
119.871   0.401 206.257
```

**Edit2**
The code works fine on the login node -- each job takes 6 seconds serially, and 24 jobs in parallel takes 12 seconds.  So how do compute nodes differ in general from login nodes?

**Edit3**
**Solved**
It turns out that I have been using `ibrun` in my shell script, which sends the job to multiple threads.  However, R uses something called "thread parallelism", in which the parallel backend is called from within R, rather than from the shell script that calls the R job.  If you call multiple threads from the batching command, the cluster will make the parallel job run *in each core*.  Hence the speed that was a rough multiple of the number of cores.  So, moral of the story: only ask the batching system for one thread on a shared resource system, and let R handle the number of actual cores that get used.  And this issue will probably only be relevant on shared supercomputers with batching systems.

Comment: Did you rerun `st = proc.time()` before running the parallel version?

Comment: Yeah I embedded it in the function to make sure that indeed it was getting executed slowly, rather than parallel execution failing.

Comment: So the answer then is "no".  Do you not see where `st` is defined outside your function?

Comment: You're correct that this was sloppy coding, but renaming `st` to `sti` within the function doesn't change the time it takes to do one iteration.

Comment: How long did the *aggregate* operation take? Disregard the "elapsed" field (see `?proc.time`). Can you show us a comparison of `system.time(x <- analyze_(xygrid[1,]))` with `system.time(output <- a_ply(xygrid,1,analyze_, .parallel=T))`?

Comment: @r2evans see edits.  I can't do a full `a_ply(xygrid,1,analyze_, .parallel=T))`, as this would take more than one day.  But I can compare it to a serial job, using a 24-row subset of my data. You'll see that parallel is indeed slower.  I don't know what could be causing this.

Comment: Interesting. What data is used by `analyze_`? Is anything (whether explicitly passed or referencing the global env) relatively large? That's been something that impacted me in the past.

Comment: Not really.  The function loads a datafile from a directory that is roughly 100 rows and 30 columns.  It spends the bulk of its time running an analysis and then re-running the same analysis on a perturbed version of the data (i.e.: bootstrapping).

Comment: I have the same issues: tested this on multiple clusters and windows local beats it hands down by many factors